# return statements are not coming out right

Tags: java, equals

> I need to code a method that checks if:
>
> A = all numbers are equal.
> B = no numbers are equal.
> C = at least two numbers are equal.
>
> Im just beginning to learn all this in uni but I cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong in this method which needs to return the given conditions e.g("A", "B", "C").

```
public static int checkNumbers(int x, int y, int z) 
{ 
    int A,B,C;

    A = 'A';
    B = 'B';
    C = 'C';

    if((x == y) && (y == z))
    {
        return A;
    }
    else if ((x == y) || (x == z) || (y == z))
    {
        return C;

    }
    else
    {
        return B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what conditions the code doesn't work for?  What's the input and what's the output?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `checkNumbers`? What are `x,y,z`?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared A, B and C as integers and then assigned to them a 'Char'.
Maybe try

```
public static char checkNumbers(int x, int y, int z) 
{ 
    char A,B,C;

    A = 'A';
    B = 'B';
    C = 'C';

    if((x == y) && (y == z))
    {
        return A;
    }
    else if ((x == y) || (x == z) || (y == z))
    {
        return C;

    }
    else
    {
        return B;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use a String

```
public static String checkNumbers(int x, int y, int z) 
{ 
    String A,B,C;

    A = "A";
    B = "B";
    C = "C";

    if((x == y) && (y == z))
    {
        return A;
    }
    else if ((x == y) || (x == z) || (y == z))
    {
        return C;

    }
    else
    {
        return B;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> return the given conditions e.g("A", "B", "C")

Then you should return a `String` (or `char`), not `int`.

```
public static String checkNumbers(int x, int y, int z) { 
    if (x == y && y == z) {
        return "A";
    } else if (x == y || x == z || y == z) {
        return "C";
    } else {
        return "B";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(checkNumbers(0, 0, 0)); // A 
   System.out.println(checkNumbers(0, 0, 1)); // C
   System.out.println(checkNumbers(0, 1, 2)); // B
}
```

Otherwise, you need to print `(char) checkNumbers(...)` to cast the `int` return value into a printable character